# QGIS 3.22.16 How to join two table with different values

Tags: qgis, line, vector, spatial-join, select-by-location

I am using QGIS 2.22 16. Working on a road network shapefile I was asked to add in this layer the road names from another road network shapefile. I thought about using the join tool. Unfortunately, the two shapefiles do not have a similar Key ID. Is it a way to add this attribute (Road Names) in this layer.

Comment: Are you asking how to `join attributes by location`?